# PHP: array_rand random value

Tags: php, arrays, random

I need to get a random value with php function *array_rand*.

```
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
echo $input[$rand_keys[1]] . "\n";
```

How to can I get value from this? Like a `$input[$rand_keys];`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean how you get the names? Don't you get 2 random names from the array with the above code? Like here http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Sounds like he's looking for a way to get a bunch of array values at once, given a bunch of keys.

Comment: Give some more details on what you mean by $input[$rand_keys] -- what kind of result are you trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

So many ways to do it, including simple loops... Here's probably the most compact one-liner:

```
$randValues = array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(array_rand($input, 2)));
```

Comment: Hi, this is working fine for limit > 1.. but it's not working when i give the limit to 1.. it's displaying warnings as:: `array_flip() expects parameter 1 to be array` and ` array_intersect_key(): Argument #2 is not an array` ...... do u have any solution for that..

Comment: If you just need 1, then just do `$input[array_rand($input)]`. The return value of `array_rand` is very different for 1 and >1.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen a built-in way yet.  I tend to do something like this:

```
$rand_values = array_map(
    function($key) use ($input) { return $input[$key]; },
    $rand_keys
);
```

But that's because i thoroughly detest repeating myself.  :P

Answer (score 0):

You are using it correctly. [`array_rand`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) returns a set of keys for random entries of your array. In your case, though, if you want to pick *all* entries in a randomized fashion you should be using:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 5);
```

If you want an array out of this, you could just do `$rand_values = array($input[$rand_keys[0]], $input[$rand_keys[1]], $input[$rand_keys[2]], $input[$rand_keys[3]], $input[$rand_keys[4]]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Change:
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 2);
to
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);